# How to pass ID from object from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to pass a view data(integer) from object rather than the whole object to another controller action with integer argument.

View

```
@model HWA.ECom.Entity.Customer
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Customer", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id)

   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Delete(Int32 id)
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EComLocalConnection"].ConnectionString;

        CustomerRepository customerRepository = new CustomerRepository(connectionString);
        return View("ShowMessage", customerRepository.Delete(id));
    }
```

Repository

```
public Boolean Delete(Int32 id)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_Customer_Delete", con);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Id",id);
        Int32 count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (count > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: Your method needs to be `[HttpPost]public ActioResult Delete(Int32 id)` (and it needs to return an `ActionResult`)

Comment: You Can use hidden field to set Id and on submit it will be posted to controller. Make that Delete controller method is HttpPost and return ActioResult.

Comment: Sorry, I should have attached controller rather than repository code. I have updated my question, please take you guys time to review it. Thanks.

Comment: And what exactly doesn't work in your case? This should be working correctly. I mean, if you intention is to have a form with textbox where you fill in user's ID and submit it to delete the user.